# Compiler independent C++ properties

Tags: c++, properties, cross-platform

Microsoft Visual C++ compiler has the property declaration construction

```
__declspec( property( get=get_func_name, put=put_func_name ) )
```

Is there a compiler independent version of Microsoft C++ __declspec(property(...)) or another analogs?

Comment: A two second google search yielded this: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/516976-__declspecproperty-support-in-gcc-4x-or-c0x/ Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can implement properties using template programming.:-)

Comment: @Nawaz: you can but that involves having data members of non-0 size, that is, it leads to increases memory use. A compiler-level implementation would be free from this drawback. Another point is that properties are practically useless in C++.

Comment: @Maxim: No. I think it can implemented without memory overhead.

Comment: I don't think it can be done without memory overhead because there must be data members accessible using `object.member` syntax and the data members can't be of zero size (unlike empty base classes). So, a property member is going to occupy at least 1 byte in the object.

Comment: @Maxim: What I mean is that if you want a property called `Height` of type `int`, then it will use only `sizeof(int)` bytes. Not more than that. And that is not called overhead. Overhead is when you use more memory than `sizeof(PropertyType)`.

Comment: You are talking about data members with overloaded assignment and cast operators. These are not properties.

Comment: @Maxim: What do you mean by property then? I mean it to be like CLR properties in .NET, behavior-wise. That is, you can make a property read only if you want to.

Comment: Property does not require any underlying storage. See the second paragraph of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1384.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

As usual, an identifier preceded by `__` is reserved to the compiler. In C++03 you have `__cpluscplus` (to identify C++ vs C), `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. All those are preprocessor entities.

In C++0x, the difference is blurred by the introduction of the `__attribute__` word which is the first I know of that has semantics value, but it still does not do what you're looking for.

**EDIT**: Addressing @James spot on comment.

Comment: C++03 has a few `__` identifiers too:  `__cplusplus`, `__LINE__`, etc.  But, of course, aside from those, any others are compiler-specific and should be avoided wherever possible.

Answer (score 2):

As Nicola Musatti says, there was a [Borland proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1384.pdf), primarily because Borland Delphi uses Properties heavily, and C++Builder (their C++ 'equivalent' to Delphi) [therefore requires it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Property).

In C++Builder, the code looks a bit like this.

```
__property __int64 Size = {read=GetSize, write=SetSize};
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Similar mechanisms were proposed to the C++ standard committee but none was ever accepted [(Here is one such proposal from Borland](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1384.pdf)).

I've seen template based toy implementations, but they tend to be too inconvenient to be of practical use, the major problems being:

- As nested class instances are not members of the enclosing class (as are Java inner class instances), you have to explicitly "connect" a property to its enclosing class, which makes declaration and initialization cumbersome.
- There is no way to call function-like entities without parentheses, so you cannot invoke a custom-made property as if you were accessing a variable.

Comment: Borland proposal here. My google-fu is working...  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1384.pdf